# Count cells containing strings not equal to many things with multiple criteria- Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have two data tables on different tabs, named July and August. Within these tabs are columns with names, groups, and divisions. I am trying to compare the July names against the August names and return the number of unique names within each group/division.

I have used a Countifs function to isolate the number of names within each group and division for both July and August, but can not find a good formula to compare the string of July names against the string of August names and return the number of unique strings.

I have tried a few different nested =Sumproduct functions, including Sumproduct(Countifs(), but I am not sure how to apply this to cells containing strings. I have also tried a =Sumproduct(--(INSA(Match())). Are these functions logical to get to my end result?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.
Please read [ask]. Then [edit] your question and add the code you've tried so far. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? 
Good luck!

Comment: Agreed with @Robert. Without seeing some sample data any answer could be a bad answer. Having that said, I think you can try using **VLOOKUP** to look up the Names in July table from August table, and do another **VLOOKUP** to look up August Names from July Table, a `FALSE` result indicates a unique name that only appeared once either in July or August table.

Answer (score 0):

> There is no snap is no snap in your question, due to we not sure what
>   you trying to ask.
>
> However here you go for an example answer, which worked based on few
>   understanding in your question.  If this is not what you expected,
>   please help me to get the snaps of your data. So that will solve your
>   task.

**Answer:**

**Here is Example Of July Sheet.**

Formula Used in "`D3`"  `=COUNTIFS(August!A:A,A3&B3&C3)`

you can use `Countif()` also for single category (this scenario also single category) , here i used `Countifs()` for any addition category.

Drop The Same Formula To Down Arrow Which is in "`D3`" to Apply All

the Formula Which is taking count of `Name&Group&Division` from August Sheet.

[image]

**Here is Example Of August Sheet.**.

Here I made a duplicate reference of concatenating each columns, it will be helpful to identify the duplicates easily.

Formula Used In "`A3`"   `=B3&C3&D3` (or) `=CONCATENATE(B3,C3,D3)`

Drop The Same Formula To Down Arrow Which is in "`A3`"  to Apply All

[image]